# How can i get the controller name in jsp?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I am developing a very small web application with spring mvc, In my jsp view that is returned by controller,I want to get the name of  the controller.

One way is we can pass the name in ModelandView,But I don wan to do that.
As  I am sending a list of some other oblect.

I am looking for other best solution if any.

With Advance thanks,
Laxmi

Comment: This link http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?73731-How-to-get-controller-name-in-jsp-view-file suggests what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: @Rupak: Yes i had gone through that link.Is that the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ways that came through my mind:

1. Pass it in the request using `request.setAttribute("name", "controller name");`. 
   Then in your jsp you can call `${ param.name }`.
2. Pass it in the session using `session.setAttribute("name", "controller name");`. 
   Then in your jsp you can call `${ name }`.